# Handling errors in potentially incomplete responses

Tags: python, performance, error-handling, exception

I am using the library `geoip2` to get Geolocation of many IP adderesses

```py
"""
input:
        str:   IP
output ordered list: 
    [0] str:   City, State, Country
    [1] tuple: (Lat; Log)
    [2] str:   Postal
"""

for i in pd.unique(df_to_print['requesterIp']):
    res = reader.city(i)
    # NOTE: Second snippet is added here
    myDict[i] = [res.city.names['en'] + ", " + res.subdivisions[0].names['en'] + ", " +  res.country.names['en'],(res.location.latitude, res.location.longitude), res.postal.code]

# output:  ['Calgary, Alberta, Canada', (50.9909, -113.9632), 'T2C']
```

Sometimes the response, which is in JSON, is missing some fields. This causes a exception.

Here is my proposed "fix", the code works as intended, but looks sinful

```py
try:
    city = res.city.names['en']
except:
    city = "-1" 

try:
    state = res.subdivisions[0].names['en']
except:
    state = "-1" 
    
try:
    country =  res.country.names['en']
except:
    country =  "-1"
    
try:
    cord = (res.location.latitude, res.location.longitude)
except:
    cord = (-1, -1)

postal = res.postal.code if res.postal.code is not None else -1


print([city + ", " + state + ", " +  country, cord, postal]) 
# output: ['-1, -1, China', (34.7725, 113.7266), -1]
```

What can I do to make my code more professional and efficient?

(this will run for apx. 100K unique IPs, several times a hour; DB is local)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. Don't use [exceptions for flow control](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/189222/13162) unless you have to for [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) or other reasons. "[Tell, don't ask](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html)" is a useful guideline when requesting something from a piece of state the current code has no control over, but it's not a law. In your code there is no chance of `res.country.names` changing while running `res.country.names.get('en', "-1")`, and that is much clearer than using exception handling to set a default.
2. You almost always want to catch *specific* exceptions.
3. When retrieving values from a `dict` you can use `my_dict.get("key", default)` to get a default value if the key does not exist.
4. Use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) rather than `+` to create formatted strings.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the first point ? Exceptions-flow control etc

Comment: @anki The most common use of exceptions is for handling (or choosing not to handle) errors, failures, or unexpected conditions. If the situation is expected, then it's often better to use some kind of `if` statement, since exceptions have high overhead, and need to be used carefully to avoid catching unrelated errors. That said, there are situations where exception based flow control is the lesser of two evils, and "asking for forgiveness rather than permission" is sometimes seen as a good approach, although it's less common than it was.

Comment: @anki the first point is wrong. Using exceptions for control flow is a widely accepted in the python community: even standard and famous libraries are using exceptions for control flow and it's considered to be **pythonic**. This misconception comes from C++/Java/what else programmers, where exceptions have a lot of overhead and are not really efficient.

Comment: @Gsk I agree that exceptions should not be used by beginners if they don't know how to use it properly (and this is not about efficiency at all)  See this series https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W7fIy_54y-w . I just wanted another viewpoint on this by the answerer here.

Comment: @anki thanks for the link. Yes, you have to know how to use exceptions and the implementation here is poor. Still, Python uses exceptions even in the [for loop implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration)

Comment: @Gsk In this question, point 3 removes the need for exceptions completely. I saw that and my first thought was to find a way to set default values in a better way.

Comment: The source for point 1 directly states that exceptions are used for control flow in Python. On the ***first*** line

Comment: @spyr03 & others, I've updated to explain why exceptions for flow control is a bad idea for this specific code sample.

Comment: Your example for point 1 assumes that res has an attribute country, and that attribute itself has and attribute names, which has a function `get`. If my reading of it is correct, the (API)[https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-python#what-data-is-returned] in question explicitly calls out that not all attributes will be populated. I'm not convinced the code will be better off after accounting for all possible errors and exceptions in this case. How would you write the code?

Comment: @spyr03 Why not post an answer yourself?

Comment: Because I don't want to post an answer. How would you write the code without exceptions as control flow, and why is it better?

Comment: @l0b0 Thank you for the most recent edit (expansion to point 1). It provided needed clarification

Comment: "Generally, the use of exceptions for control flow is an anti-pattern, with many notable situation - and language-specific (see for example Python)" Isn't the OP's code _Python_? Now I understand EAFP isn't the answer to everything, like the OP's code, but drinking the LBYL kool-aid can be just as bad. Otherwise this is a pretty poor answer cause you've not explained anything except the first point.